# Tinkerprop Gremlin: Order by the weight of relations

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Here is my test database:

```
    graph = TinkerGraph.open()
    g = graph.traversal()
    v1 = g.addV("person").property(id, 1).property("name", "1").next()
    v2 = g.addV("person").property(id, 2).property("name", "2").next()
    v3 = g.addV("person").property(id, 3).property("name", "3").next()
    v4 = g.addV("person").property(id, 4).property("name", "4").next()
    v5 = g.addV("person").property(id, 5).property("name", "5").next()
    v6 = g.addV("person").property(id, 6).property("name", "6").next()
    g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v2).property(id, 10).property("weight", 0.4)
    g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v2).property(id, 11).property("weight", 0.4)
    g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v4).property(id, 12).property("weight", 0.2)
    g.addE("knows").from(v1).to(v6).property(id, 13).property("weight", 1)
    g.addE("knows").from(v2).to(v3).property(id, 14).property("weight", 0.4)
    g.addE("knows").from(v3).to(v5).property(id, 15).property("weight", 0.4)
    g.addE("knows").from(v4).to(v5).property(id, 16).property("weight", 0.4)
    g.addE("knows").from(v4).to(v5).property(id, 17).property("weight", 0.3)
    g.addE("knows").from(v6).to(v5).property(id, 18).property("weight", 0.4)
    g.addE("knows").from(v6).to(v5).property(id, 19).property("weight", 0.4)
    g.addE("knows").from(v6).to(v5).property(id, 20).property("weight", 0.2)
```

I'm trying to get shorters path (minimum sum of weight) from a person to another.

Here is my current query:

```
    g.V(1).repeat(bothE("knows").bothV()).until(hasId(6)).path().as("path").map(unfold().coalesce(values("weight"), constant(0)).sum()).as("Cost").select("path", "Cost").limit(10);
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[10][1-knows->2],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1.4]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[11][1-knows->2],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1.4]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[12][1-knows->4],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1.2]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:2]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[10][1-knows->2],v[1],e[10][1-knows->2],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1.8]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[10][1-knows->2],v[1],e[11][1-knows->2],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1.8]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[10][1-knows->2],v[1],e[12][1-knows->4],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1.6]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[10][1-knows->2],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:2.4]
    ==>[path:[v[1],e[10][1-knows->2],v[2],e[10][1-knows->2],v[1],e[13][1-knows->6],v[6]],Cost:1.8]
```

I'm not finding how to order by the Cost. I'm trying with the step `order()` and `by("Cost")` but it didn't works, it never return result. Here is one of my test that return nothing.

```
g.V(1).repeat(bothE("knows").bothV()).until(hasId(6)).path().as("path").map(unfold().coalesce(values("weight"), constant(0)).sum()).as("Cost").select("path").order().by(select("Cost")).limit(10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is running into an infinite loop. In your first query, you just got lucky as `repeat()` was aware of the `limit()` step and thus stopped after emitting 10 vertices. With `order().by()` included, `repeat()` can no longer do that as `order().by()` needs all results before it can order anything.

Furthermore, there's a better way to keep track of the cost:

```
g.withSack(0).V(1).
  repeat(bothE("knows").sack(sum).by("weight").otherV().simplePath()).
    until(hasId(6)).
  order().
    by(sack()).
  limit(10).
  path()
```